# See next item in FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android, fragmentpageradapter

Is it possible to setup FragmentPagerAdapter in a way, that I can see full 1st item on a screen and a part of a second item on the right? So that user knows that she/he has to swipe to show the next one item?

**UPDATE:**

Like this:[image: Fragment A doesn't fill whole screen, Fragment B is being seen]

Fragment A doesn't fill whole screen, Fragment B is being seen, a part of it. So user knows that sth is there and he/she has to swipe to see it

Comment: What do you mean by see? So the view on the right is "overlapping" the current view, or the current view doesn't go to the edge of the screen, and you can just skim the next view?

Comment: Fragment A doesn't fill whole screen, Fragment B is being seen, a part of it. So user knows that sth is there and he/she has to swipe to see it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a look at this: [ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter](https://github.com/thecodepath/android_guides/wiki/ViewPager-with-FragmentPagerAdapter#viewpager-with-visible-adjacent-pages)

Comment: Found similar answer some time ago and totally forgot about this question. This works too, thanks.